# Saving Filename based on time

Tags: c#, datetime, filenames

I'm making a basic program, and when it comes to saving data I'm trying to put it into a .txt - which is working just fine. Problem is, I can't save the seconds/hours in addition to the date, so my solution was to just get the date and then put 1, 2, 3 respectively on most recent files. The code I made was:

```
static string FileName()
{
    string fileName = "";
    char last = ' ';
    int lastDigit = 0;
    string lastDigitString = "";
    string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 
    if (File.Exists(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy" + "1") + ".txt"))
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFileName + ".txt");
        last = fileName[fileName.Length - 1];
        lastDigit = int.Parse(last.ToString());
        lastDigit = lastDigit + 1;
        lastDigitString = lastDigit.ToString();
        newFileName = fileName + lastDigitString;
    }
    else
    {
        newFileName = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy" + "1");
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

with newFileName being defined as a global variable at the top.

```
public static string newFileName = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy" + "1");
```

I've been messing around with some things might be out of place. My solution was to get the filename and then take off the .txt - which would then leave me with just the name where I get the last digit of the name and then increase it by one, then add it to the end of a new file name. It goes 'FileName1' then 'FileName12' which is what I hoped to get, but once there it just keeps adding to 'FileName12' which is obviously from the appending set to true, but I hoped for a 'FileName123'.

Comment: There is a DateTime constructor that allows for access to hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. See the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a requirement not to use the Hour/Minute/Second for your file name?
You are using `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(..)`, which will strip out the hour/minute/second data. You can use `DateTime.Now.ToString(..)` to reserve the sub-day data.

You'll need to provide your own format string to generate a file-name-friendly output.

Comment: Could use the `s` format, e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToString("s");`

Comment: There isn't  a particular reason - I couldn't get it to work so I opted for a different way. I can see the problem why my current program isn't working - no clue what I can do about it though. And yeah, I'll try to figure out a string format for filename friendliness.

Comment: @MichalCiechan, `DateTime.Now.ToString("s")` has colons in the output which is an invalid file name character.

Comment: @vK31RON, did you try `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`?

Comment: @BabakNaffas I've just figured out a way to format it the way I want - yeah, I think I did put Now but then someone else said that I should use Date and go about it a different way, so I opted for that way since it seemed easier :P

Answer (score 1):

This is because time has colon : and it is not supported as windows file